# API's not showing after migrating WSO2 API Manager to 2.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have done the migration of API Manager from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 
by following https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromthePreviousRelease-Step2-UpgradeAPIManagerto2.1.0

It looked fine and I dont see any errors in logs.
But none of my API's are visible in the publisher.
But in the store ,I can see the existing Applications.

Also in the logs ,I can see my API's are getting mapped ;but now showing up in API Manager

```
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,538]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every : 15s
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,544]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing Synapse at : Mon Nov 13 23:07:43 UTC 2017
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,551]  INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,553]  INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,554]  INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,608]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _sandbox_key_error_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,610]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _resource_mismatch_handler_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,618]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _cors_request_handler_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,646]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : fault was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,649]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _production_key_error_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,651]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _build_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,653]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : outDispatchSeq was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,658]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : main was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,659]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _auth_failure_handler_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,664]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _token_fault_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,675]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : dispatchSeq was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,676]  INFO - DependencyTracker Sequence : _throttle_out_handler_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:43,684]  INFO - DependencyTracker Proxy service : WorkflowCallbackService was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,157]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : admin--Auth:vv1 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,160]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : _WSO2AMAuthorizeAPI_ was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
***
```

> [2017-11-13 23:07:44,193]  INFO - DependencyTracker API :
>   admin--MenuProfileAPIs:vv1 was added to the Synapse configuration
>   successfully
>       [2017-11-13 23:07:44,194]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : admin--testGroup:vv1 was added to the Synapse configuration
>   successfully
>       [2017-11-13 23:07:44,640]  INFO - DependencyTracker API : admin--SettingsAPIs:vv1 was added to the Synapse configuration
>   successfully

---

```
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,642]  INFO - DependencyTracker Inbound Endpoint : WebSocketInboundEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,642]  INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,643]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : SERVER_HOST was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,643]  INFO - DependencyTracker Local entry : SERVER_IP was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,645]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions...
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,747]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
[2017-11-13 23:07:44,747]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar -
```

How Can i debug this issue?What could be the possible causes for this.

I tried to create a new API with the same name of an existing API.Its not letting me create .It says duplicate.So it feels the API is existing ; but not shown in the UI.
I went to Manage Subscriptions in the Publisher and I can see the API's listed there. If I click the API's , I can see them.EVerything looks intact.But its not listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check followings

- Verify whether same APIM and Registry databases from the 2.0.0 deployment is pointed to 2.1.0.
- Re-index the API data as stated in step 4 of "https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromthePreviousRelease-Step2-UpgradeAPIManagerto2.1.0"

Comment: I just  tried to create a new API with the name of an older existing one..It says Duplicate Name... So it looks like API's exists ;but not visible in the API publisher

Comment: Verify whether same APIM and Registry databases from the 2.0.0 deployment is pointed to 2.1.0.
Which file is this?

Comment: That's in the master-datasources.xml file and registry.xml. If you get an error for duplicate APIs, it looks like you have correctly pointed the DBs. Therefore, please re-index, strat the server and try after few seconds.

Comment: I did that many times... I deleted solr folder ; renamed lastAccessTimeLocation 
Is there any any manual indexing which i can try? I am stuck here

Comment: I went to Manage Subscriptions in the Publisher and I can see the API's listed there. If I click the API's , I can see them.EVerything looks intact.But its not listing.

Comment: INFO - AMQConnection Unable to connect to broker at tcp://:5672  I have this error in the logs when i try to start my application which invokes the login api

Comment: Please login to the management console (/carbon) and access the registry through Browse->registry menu option. Then go to _system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/path path. Do you see the API related entries there?

Comment: I see every API under a different path as /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/

Under application data , I dont have path folder

Comment: Sorry, path part was mistakenly appended there. So looks good. Only problem seems to be with indexing. Is this a single node setup?

Comment: Yes..its single node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158977/discussion-between-jocket-and-lakmali-erandi).

Comment: Unable to connect to broker at tcp://mydevwso2.ca:5672 {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection}
org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection

I have this error in API manager log